# Running project on Nginx without specifying port

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx

I'm running PHP project in Symfony, using docker for db, nginx and php. I'm not sure what's wrong, because this projects used to run on different PC, but for some reason I cannot run it on this one without specifying port in the url. So `http://bp.project:82` works, but `http://bp.project` does not.
This is my config for nginx:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name bp.project;
    root /var/www/html/public/;
    index index.php;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            # Om nom nom cookies
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'PATCH') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'DELETE') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # location /assets/ {
    #
    # }
}
```

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/:delegated
      - ./.docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./.docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      bp_project_network:
        aliases:
          - bp.project
    ports:
      - "82:80"

  php:
    image: thecodingmachine/php:8.0-v4-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/:delegated
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      PHP_EXTENSION_INTL: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__MODE: "debug,develop"
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__CLIENT_PORT: 10000
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__IDEKEY: PHPSTORM
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__START_WITH_REQUEST: trigger
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=bp.project"
      PHP_EXTENSION_PGSQL: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_PDO_PGSQL: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_MYSQLI: 0
    #      STARTUP_COMMAND_1: composer install
    #      STARTUP_COMMAND_2: php bin/console do:mi:m --no-interaction
    #      STARTUP_COMMAND_3: php bin/console do:f:l --group=default --no-interaction
    networks:
      - bp_project_network

  database:
    image: dockette/postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=bp_project
    volumes:
      - database-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5421:5432"
    networks:
      - bp_project_network

  adminer:
    image: dockette/adminer:dg
    ports:
      - "1112:80"
    networks:
      - bp_project_network

volumes:
  ###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database-volume:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

networks:
  bp_project_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Can you help me to run this website without specifying the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mapping the Nginx port to port 82, so that's why you have to specify it.

To not have to specify it, you need to map it to port 80, the default HTTP port.

To do that, you need to change this part of your docker compose file from

```
ports:
  - "82:80"
```

to

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

Comment: I see. But what if I wanted to run multiple projects at the same time, again, without specifying the port? Is it possible?

Comment: You can only have one program listening on a port. So what you can do, is let Nginx listen on port 80 and route the traffic to the correct project using `proxy_pass`. For instance based on host name, so `http://bp.project1` goes to one container and `http://bp.project2` goes to another. You can also route based on the path, so `http://bp.project/project1/` goes to project1 and `http://bp.project/project2/` goes to project2.